# How can I manage the apk unistallation

Tags: android

I have an App that write some file in the SD Card used to store data object. When the user delete the app or the app is updated, these files remains in the SD and aren't removed with apk. This could lead to some annoying issue if I change the data management structure of my App, really difficult to fix simply checking if these dat file are already present for various reason.

Is there a way to say to Android OS to remove also these files when the app is unistalled or updated without manual intervention of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the update case, yes. Implement a `BroadcastReceiver` subclass...

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getData().equals(Uri.parse("package:<YOUR APP'S PACKAGE>"))) {
            // Clean up for the new app install
        }
    }
}
```

... and then add a `<receiver>` tag to your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name =".MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
       <data android:scheme="package"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

There is also a `PACKAGE_REMOVED` action, but the `Intent` with that action fires *after* apps are removed, so you don't have a chance to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

> When the user delete the app or the app is updated, these files remains in the SD and aren't removed with apk

Then you should be storing them in `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()`. Files in those directories are stored on external storage but are automatically removed when the app is uninstalled.